# How to set $LS_COLORS variable in TTY

Tags: ls, tty, colors

I'm trying to make my console gorgeous with setting custom dircolors. For that I'm doing

```
eval $(dircolors "dircolors.ansi.dark")
```

where dircolors.ansi.dark is my custom file with preffered colors.

Everything works good, except tty (you know it's console without graphical interface. You can call it with pressing CTRL+ALT+F2, F3, etc.

Inside that console I don't have colors for ls command, and if I check echo $LS_COLORS it's empty.

How to set LS_COLORS there?

Answer (score 0):

Your `dircolors.ansi.dark` file probably does not include the appropriate terminal type identifier for the text-mode console, causing the `dircolors` command to do nothing when run on a console session.

Go to the console, login and type `echo $TERM`. You'll get the name of the terminal type, usually it's `linux` when on the console but it might be something different depending on your distribution and its configuration.

Then, make sure your `dircolors.ansi.dark` file includes a `TERM` line that matches the terminal type used on the console. There may be several TERM lines, and they may include wildcards. See `dircolors --print-database | less` for an example.

Comment: Sorry complete forgot to mention that, actually it does have linux, here is that file https://pastebin.com/g4NMGzXY